# Attempting to Fork Private Repo

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to fork a private repository, but am met with "Where should we fork this repository?" and it displays the organization of my part time client. I do not want to fork this private repo to them, but for myself. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

When you fork a repo, the modal box you are describing should have your profile and organizations you are a member of.

If your profile is not in the list, most probably the repo owner disallowed public forks. You'll need to get a subscription and then do a private fork.

Comment: The weird thing is, i show up on the organization's list when I go to their team members section.

Comment: Yeah, but it does not mean you can create private repo "under" your personal profile. Basically, organizations are just like profiles. In your case, organization has a paid subscription so it can have private repos in it (`org/repo`). But, your personal profile doesn't, so you can't fork it into your profile (`you/repo`).